# End/Stop a NSFileHandle socket server

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sockets

I created a server using a NSFileHandle and it works just fine the problem is how to end it. (close it) I cannot dealloc it because I'm using ARC and I really have to find a way to end it. Here is how I started the server:

```
socketPort = [[NSSocketPort alloc] initWithTCPPort:portNumber];
    int fd = [socketPort socket];
    fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fd
                                    closeOnDealloc:YES];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about [`[NSFileHandle closeFile]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/closeFile):

```
[fileHandle closeFile];
fileHandle = nil;    // ARC equiv of release
```

(I would imagine the `[NSFileHandle dealloc]` method calls `closeFile` anyway, but calling it directly is more obvious of your intent and is more defensive).

If you want to stop `socketPort` from listening, then this will probably work:

```
socketPort = nil;
```

**WARNING:** [According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH4-SW3) you aren't supposed to use `NSSocketPort` and `NSFileHandler` for general networking.

Comment: This dosent stop the file handle from listening it continues on listening and the client dosent lose the connection (I'm using terminal telnet client)

Comment: @user1014334 Wouldn't listening be related to `socketPort` and not `fileHandle`?  Perhaps `socketPort = nil;`?

Comment: Well can you give me a basic tutorial on making a socket server without nssocket port and fileHandle? (I tried to find a few that are 100% cocoa that can run on an osx and iphone but I failed) Can you please give me one? thank you very very much!

Comment: @user1014334 No.  That's what the Apple documentation is for.